# Force convergence in Wannier orbitals based DFT code

Tags: density-functional-theory, geometry-optimization, plane-waves

I am working on Pt(111) / nanoparticles with various ligands, I am mainly using two softwares:

- A well known general purpose plane-wave code (Quantum Espresso).
- A less known software that is also aiming general purpose with plane-wave accuracy, the theory is a little bit more complicated (Wannier functions). It has been actively developed for 20 years.

The second software has difficulties performing geometry optimisations to a force threshold that I would consider not really tight (0.25 eV/A). The force gradient has an oscillating behaviour, it is getting down but really slowly (50 geometry iterations to get to 0.4 eV/A) as a comparison Quantum Espresso get to 0.01 eV/A in 30 iterations.

From what I have seen so far this problem seems to be a general problem and not only restricted to my system.

I have different persons telling me two possible explanations:

- This problem is inherent to Wannier wavefunctions DFT, due to the truncation applied on the orbitals, forces will have some noise.
- This problem is due to a bad geometry optimiser which needs to be rewritten.

Is there anyone on this Stack Exchange with experience on this topic or any references that might help my case?

Comment: Can you name the second software?

Comment: @TristanMaxson I am afraid I can't, if this makes the question too general/hard to answer I will delete it.

Comment: @Okano I don't know if it would be answerable without knowing the software. The details of how the optimizer works are likely highly dependent on the program and any number of different factors/parameters could cause problems in specific cases.  I suppose a question about the first bullet (are Wannier functions susceptible to noise in computed forces?) would be workable without knowing the software. But if you want an answer that relates to a specific program, I think it will be impossible without knowing what that program is.

Comment: Even if it is proprietary/closed-source, there may be other users who have used it or develop for it who have some sense of these details and could describe them in a way that wouldn't violate any sort of nondisclosure requirement. Also, if it really is crucial that you not reveal the name of the 2nd program the details "uses Wannier functions, developed for roughly 20 years" narrows down considerably what program it could be, assuming it's publicly available.

Comment: Does this other program allow you to tune these parameters, either in the code or in your input? I would think you could alter the truncation radius for the Wannier functions to test if that is the cause of the noise in the forces.

Comment: I have met this problem before with NGWF methods. I strongly recommend determining the noise in the forces (ideally with a numerical derivative of the energy with respect to atomic positions) and then increasing the truncation radius of the NGWFs and repeating. Standard BFGS/LBFGS methods are not very tolerant of noise. Are you optimising the NGWFs or just the density kernel? I'd be surprised if the geometry optimiser is as poor as this, but if it has an ASE interface, you could try its geometry optimisation methods.

Comment: @PhilHasnip Thank you for your comment, I agree with you: I would also be surprised if the geometry optimiser is that bad. I optimise both NGWFs and the density kernel. I just launched some tests with higher radius to see how this impact the forces. Just to be sure, when you say "numerical derivative" you mean finite difference?

Comment: Yes, ideally a centred difference for each atom, and then compare that with the calculated forces. If your research system is large, you might want to do that test for a smaller system, but make sure it has the same elements and same calculation quality. There is also noise in the forces due to not converging to exactly the Kohn-Sham ground state; this is true for the plane-wave codes as well, but the Pulay forces might make it worse so it's probably worth tightening the convergence tolerances and checking the noise with respect to that, as well.

Comment: Actually, if you just want an initial test of the forces you could just do the centred difference with respect to just one or two atoms, and check those forces. If you do this for a model test system, remember not to put the atoms on symmetry sites or all the forces will be zero by symmetry!

Comment: Any update on this issue? If you'd like to drop me an email, I can look at this in more detail and we can post the answer here when we've resolved it.

Comment: @Okano any update? Did you email Phil? I'm also not sure why I was the only one to vote on this question over 5.5 months, see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/366/5).

Comment: @NikeDattani I did send an email to Phil, I don't think I received any answer yet. We used different optimisers (ASE) with a wrapper to the code and the convergence seems to be slightly better. I still need to perform force tests using finite difference and a few more tests.

Comment: @Okano have you got a response to the email now?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.